# Error 8336 when connecting the admin server in Progress Explorer

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm getting "Unable to Connect to Admin Server. Ensure Admin Server is running.(8336)" error, when connecting the server from progress explorer, referred progress knowledge base but none of the conclusions worked.

I found that I am working in Progress version 11.3 and I am using progress explorer version 10.2b because I have both version installed. As there is no progress explorer found in 11.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is urgent you should, of course, call tech support.  That is what they are there for.

You have 2 versions installed.  You must use the tools that correspond with the proper version.

Not knowing which kbase entries you have already tried makes it difficult to advise you.

Adminservers can be run on non-default ports.  When there is more than one version of OpenEdge installed there will usually be multiple admin servers attempting to run.  If they are all trying to use the same port it doesn't work very well.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P10465

In the absence of or as an alternative to, the "Progress Explorer Tool" (Or "OpenEdge Explorer Tool" in later releases) you can use command line tools which are always installed.  First open a "proenv" window from the program group associated with the version that you are trying to operate with.  To check the adminserver use the "proadsv" command.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you adminserver isnt running.

In Windows: check services and start the adminserver.

Other platforms: type `proadv -start`

Progress Explorer has been replaced with the OE Explorer in later versions. It's a web based tool. You can access it at http://localhost:9090/ if your on a local machine and run default settings. Otherwise change localhost to the servername. Login credentials the first time are "admin" as both username and password.